# How to increase contrast in a PDF file?

Tags: windows, pdf, contrast, adobe-acrobat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjust PDF Contrast with Adobe Reader/Acrobat?](https://superuser.com/questions/117521/adjust-pdf-contrast-with-adobe-reader-acrobat)

I have a black and white pdf file of text. But the text is too faint and is difficult to read. Is there a way to increase the constrast, or make the grays more black? I have a computer with Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended installed, Windows 7.

Comment: I'm tempted to leave this open as the possible duplicate didn't get *any* useful answer. @Mehper