# Convert PDF to JPG images with ImageMagick - how to 0-pad file names?

Tags: imagemagick

I convert a pdf file to jpg images by using ImageMagick like this:

`convert -density 600 foo.pdf foo.jpg`

The created jpg images are named `foo-1.jpg`, `foo-10.jpg` and so on.

Is there way to 0-pad the output file names to `foo-01.jpg` etc.?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

ImageMagick accepts format specifiers in its command line:

```
convert -density 600 foo.pdf foo-%02d.jpg
```

Quote from the [doc](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php):

> **Filename References**
>
> Optionally, use an embedded formatting character to write a sequential
>   image list. Suppose our output filename is `image-%d.jpg` and our image
>   list includes 3 images. You can expect these images files to be
>   written:
>
> ```
> image-0.jpg
> image-1.jpg
> image-2.jpg
> ```

Comment: I tried this and get `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.`

Comment: It works after the fix I needed which I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion)